# Using ox-pluto to export org document to Pluto notebook

Tags: org-mode, pluto

I am trying to export an org document to a Pluto notebook. I am using the package 'ox-pluto.el'

When I run the command `M-x ox-pluto-export-as-pluto`

I get the error message

`Symbol's function definition is void: uuidgen-4`

I do not know emacs-lisp well enough to determine what is happening. I appreciate any help in this matter. Thanks
Chris